# DAX Measure to calculate the distinct feature counts across Manufacture & Products

Tags: powerbi, dax

Am trying to build a DAX Measure that would compute distinct features of Manufacturer product based on Base Manufacturer.

Table Columns as below

```
Manufacturer Product Features
Honda Civic Feature1
Honda Civic Feature2
Honda Civic Feature3
Maruti Ciaz Feature1
Maruti Ciaz Feature4
Maruti Ciaz Feature5
Toyato Camry Feature2
Toyoto Camry Feature4
Toyoto Camry Feature6
Toyoto Camry Feature7
```

When a Pivot table is created with Manufacturer as each row and  I would like to show the total features in one column and the distinct features in column 2.

```
Manufacturer - TotalCount - DistinctCountOverHonda
Honda - 3 - 3
Maruthi - 3 - 2 ( Feature4, Feature5) are the distinct features, when compared to Honda
Toyoto - 4 - 3 ( Feature4, Feature6, Feature7) are the unique features over Honda.
```

Please help me to write the measure for DistinctCountOverHonda & applying filter to remove the duplicate & keep just the unique features of Manufacturer present in Pivot table row.

In above example, I have kept Honda as a base for comparison over other manufacturers. Probably, I will add a slicer for a user to select the base manufacturer dynamically as parameter table and counts to be reflected based on user selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to find all the distinct features of both manufacturers combined and then subtract out the distinct features for Honda.

```
DistinctCountOverBase =
VAR CurrentManufacturer =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Manufacturer] )
VAR CombinedFeatures =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DISTINCT ( Table1[Features] ),
        Table1[Manufacturer] IN { CurrentManufacturer, "Honda" }
    )
VAR HondaFeatures =
    CALCULATETABLE ( DISTINCT ( Table1[Features] ), Table1[Manufacturer] = "Honda" )
RETURN
    IF (
        CurrentManufacturer = "Honda",
        COUNTROWS ( HondaFeatures ),
        COUNTROWS ( CombinedFeatures ) - COUNTROWS ( HondaFeatures )
    )
```

---

Here's a slightly more generalized solution:

```
DistinctCountOverBase =

VAR Base = "Honda"

VAR CurrentManufacturer =
    VALUES ( Table1[Manufacturer] )

VAR CombinedFeatures =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DISTINCT ( Table1[Features] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Table1 ),
            Table1[Manufacturer] IN CurrentManufacturer
                || Table1[Manufacturer] = Base
        )
    )

VAR BaseFeatures =
    CALCULATETABLE ( DISTINCT ( Table1[Features] ), Table1[Manufacturer] = Base )

RETURN

    IF (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Manufacturer] ) = Base,
        COUNTROWS ( BaseFeatures ),
        COUNTROWS ( CombinedFeatures ) - COUNTROWS ( BaseFeatures )
    )
```

Comment: Above Solution works when a manufacturer has all the features of base manufacturer along with new extra features. When a manufacturer contains completely new features over the base manufacturer, then above solution doesn't work.  Manufacturer Product Features
Honda Civic Feature1
Honda Civic Feature2
Honda Civic Feature3
Toyoto Camry Feature4
Toyoto Camry Feature6
Toyoto Camry Feature7. Now the Toyota has 3 distinct features over Honda, hence I would report the count as 3, but the above formula would result in Zero.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the logic. For your example, Combined Feature Count = |{1,2,3,4,6,7}| = 6. Honda Feature Count = |{1,2,3}| = 3. Difference = 6 - 3 = 3.

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I agree with you and your solution works like charm. 

Comment: Is there any workaround to write above measure without IN. Few of my customers use just Excel and IN is not supported on the version they use.

Comment: Yes. It's just an easier form of the older [`CONTAINS` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/contains-function-dax).