# DAX - distinct count of one column in permutations of other column

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot, dax

Given a set of data that has MRN (patient) and Dept as columns and where a patient can be seen in multiple Depts(many-to-many relationship), how can I put Dept across both row and column in pivot table and show how many distinct MRN were seen in each permutation of departments? I would also need to be able to compare groups of Dept - find distinct MRNs for one at least one Dept in a group of Depts that were also seen in at least one Dept from a different group of Depts. Hopefully the right DAX measure would accommodate this.

I've found suggestions for related questions to create a calculated column that is a copy of Dept, that way I can put Dept1 in row and Dept2 in column of a pivot table. However, I haven't figured out the DAX that will get distinct MRNs at each intersection of Depts.

Most promising, possible solution I've found is
[DAX Measure to calculate the distinct feature counts across Manufacture & Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640295/dax-measure-to-calculate-the-distinct-feature-counts-across-manufacture-produc) but I need to research CALCULATETABLE and SELECTEDVALUE more to know for sure.

[![Example][1]][1]

Here is some SQL that shows all Dept combinations and how many distinct MRNs for each combination, but it's limited to comparing two individual departments. I'd like to get this in DAX where the user could specify two individual departments, OR select a group of departments and find the distinct MRNs that were also seen in another group of departments.

```
    ; with Visits as (
    select MRN = 'M00111', Dept = 'Apollo' union all
    select MRN = 'M00111', Dept = 'EOB Ortho' union all
    select MRN = 'M00111', Dept = 'EOB Ortho' union all
    select MRN = 'M00222', Dept = 'EOB Gastro' union all
    select MRN = 'M00333', Dept = 'EOB Neuro' union all
    select MRN = 'M00333', Dept = 'NICU' union all
    select MRN = 'M00444', Dept = 'EOB Cardio' union all
    select MRN = 'M00444', Dept = 'NICU' union all
    select MRN = 'M00444', Dept = 'EOB Cardio' union all
    select MRN = 'M00444', Dept = 'EOB Neuro' union all
    select MRN = 'M00555', Dept = 'Apollo'

)
--select * from Visits

, DistinctDepts as (
    select distinct Dept from Visits
)
--select * from DistinctDepts

, AllDeptPermutations as (
    select
        Dept1 = dd1.Dept,
        Dept2 = dd2.Dept
    from
        DistinctDepts dd1 join
        DistinctDepts dd2 on 1 = 1
)
--select * from AllDeptPermutations


select
    perms.*,
    DistinctMrns = (
        select
            count(1)
        from
        (
            select v1.MRN
            from Visits v1
            where v1.Dept = perms.Dept1
            group by v1.Dept, v1.MRN
        ) dept1 join
        (
            select v2.MRN
            from Visits v2
            where v2.Dept = perms.Dept2
            group by v2.Dept, v2.MRN
        ) dept2 on dept1.MRN = dept2.MRN
    )
from
    AllDeptPermutations perms
```

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND A SOLUTION**: I decided to see what I could do in PowerBI. The example above is a simplified version, but in my actual project I have a fact table called Encounters and a dim table called Department and another dim table called Patients.

Solution: I made a copy of my fact table (Encounters2) and a copy of the Department dim table. I related Departments2 to Encounters2 and related Encounters2 to the Patients dim table. So, two identical fact tables related to the same Patients dim table, but also related to two different Department dimensions. I set the relationships from the two fact tables to the Patients table to both ways.

What this does is allows us to put two slicers on a matrix - one for each Department dim. With the relationships from each fact table going back to the Patients dim table, as each department dim filters each Encounters fact table, they essentially combine filters and propagate back to the Patients dim table. I put one Department dim as the X axis on the matrix and the other Department dim as the Y axis. I configured the slicers to allow multi-select, which means I can select one group of departments for the X axis of my matrix and select another group of departments for my Y axis of the matrix. A measure that gets distinct MRNs from the Patient dim table gives us the values we need - distinct patients that have been seen in two different groups of departments.

[image]

Not much DAX in this solution, but really just duplicating the fact table and one dimension and using two-way relationships. If someone knows a more elegant solution, I'd love to learn about it.